# Can't get my head around GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: php, mysql, sql, function

I cannot seem to get an GROUP_CONCAT query to work.

I have this tables, which I joined:

```
  stud
id | stud_name  |         
-----------------
1  | Class1     | 
2  | Class2     | 

  note
id | stud_id    |   mat_id       |   Note      | 
------------------------------------------------
1  | 1          |      1         |  10         | 
2  | 1          |      2         |  9          | 
3  | 1          |      1         |  10         |

mat
id | mat_name | 
----------------
1  | Porc     | 
2  | Vaca     |
```

Here is what I did to join them.

```
 SELECT
             `stud`.`id`
            , `mat`.`mat_name`
            , `note`.`note`

    FROM
            `stud`
   LEFT JOIN 
            `note` 
    ON
             (`stud`.`id` = `note`.`id_stud`)
   LEFT JOIN 
            `mat` 
        ON 
             (`note`.`id_mate` = `mat`.`id`)
```

Here is what I want them to look.

```
mat.id  | mat_name | Note      | 
-----------------------------
1       | Porc     | 10,10     | 
2       | Vaca     | 9         |
```

Here is how they look.

```
mat.id  | mat_name | Note      | 
-----------------------------
1       | Porc     | 10        | 
2       | Vaca     | 9         | 
1       | Port     | 10        |
```

I tried doing this.

```
 SELECT 
 `mat`.`mat_name`,
 GROUP_CONCAT(`note`.`note`) AS `note`.`note`,
FROM ( "Here is what I did to join them." )attr_groups
GROUP BY `mat`.`mat_name`;
ORDER BY `mat`.`mat_name`;
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT: If I add group by or ORDER by, no results are found. If I don't add them, the query works but its not concatenating them.**

Comment: Instead of qualifying the selected columns with their original table names, you should use the alias `attr_groups` (the original tables are not available to the outer query).  However, you actually don't need a subquery here at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT mat.id,
       mat.mat_name,
       GROUP_CONCAT(note.note) as note
FROM mat
LEFT JOIN note ON mat.id = note.mat_id
LEFT JOIN stud ON note.stud_id = stud.id     
GROUP BY mat.id, mat.mat_name
ORDER BY mat.mat_name
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9bda96/4)

Comment: If I add group by or ORDER by, no results are found. If I dont add them, the query works but its not concatenating them.

Comment: Ok thanks! I will use your answer, that proves that I am stupid at adapting it to my situation, it was not your fault. Thanks! And thank you all for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

You have error in group by.

```
GROUP BY `mat`.`mat_name`;
------------------------^^^---
```

remove `;` from query

```
SELECT
     `stud`.`id`
    , `mat`.`mat_name`
    , GROUP_CONCAT(`note`.`note`) AS Note
FROM
    `stud`
LEFT JOIN 
    `note` 
ON
     (`stud`.`id` = `note`.`id_stud`)
LEFT JOIN 
    `mat` 
ON 
     (`note`.`id_mate` = `mat`.`id`) 
GROUP BY
    `stud`.mat_id
ORDER BY
    `mat`.`mat_name`
```

Comment: EDIT: That was not the problem, but thanks for spotting it. I define the query as a variable, so I need ";" at the end, sorry for mistaking.ok. Removing! Trying and comming back. Thanks!

Comment: querry just executes "die":(

Comment: @AcelasiEu what do you mean..??

Comment: it results something like this: s
stud_id     1

mat_name    Matematica
note        2,3,8,7,6,5,4,10,10

Comment: but it should be like: stud id = 1 mat_name PORC note 10, 10, and then there should be the second row: stud_id = 1 mat_name=Vaca note 8, 7

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    m.id,
    m.mat_name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(n.Note) as grades
FROM
    mat m
LEFT JOIN note n
    ON n.mat_id = m.id
GROUP BY
    m.id
```

Comment: Will try and come back! Thanks